# LINQ to SQL - How to select specific columns and return strongly typed list

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to use LINQ to SQL to select a few specific columns from a table and return the result as a strongly typed list of objects.

For Example:

```
var result = (from a in DataContext.Persons
                              where a.Age > 18
                              select new Person
                              {
                                  Name = a.Name,
                                  Age = a.Age
                              }
                              ).ToList();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

It builds fine, but when I run it, I get the error. Explicit construction of entity type `MyEntity` in query is not allowed.

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got?

Comment: With NHibernate, this will work. Not so rigid as EF.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Basically you are doing it the right way. However, you should use an instance of the `DataContext` for querying (it's not obvious that `DataContext` is an instance or the type name from your query):

```
var result = (from a in new DataContext().Persons
              where a.Age > 18
              select new Person { Name = a.Name, Age = a.Age }).ToList();
```

Apparently, the `Person` class is your LINQ to SQL generated entity class. You should create your own class if you only want some of the columns:

```
class PersonInformation {
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Age {get;set;}
}

var result = (from a in new DataContext().Persons
              where a.Age > 18
              select new PersonInformation { Name = a.Name, Age = a.Age }).ToList();
```

You can freely swap `var` with `List<PersonInformation>` here without affecting anything (as this is what the **compiler** does).

Otherwise, if you are working locally with the query, I suggest considering an anonymous type:

```
var result = (from a in new DataContext().Persons
              where a.Age > 18
              select new { a.Name, a.Age }).ToList();
```

Note that **in all of these cases**, the `result` is **statically typed** (it's type is known at compile time). The latter type is a `List` of a compiler generated anonymous class similar to the `PersonInformation` class I wrote above. As of C# 3.0, there's no dynamic typing in the language.

### UPDATE:

If you really want to return a `List<Person>` (which might or might not be the best thing to do), you can do this:

```
var result = from a in new DataContext().Persons
             where a.Age > 18
             select new { a.Name, a.Age };

List<Person> list = result.AsEnumerable()
                          .Select(o => new Person {
                                           Name = o.Name, 
                                           Age = o.Age
                          }).ToList();
```

You can merge the above statements too, but I separated them for clarity.

Comment: Thank you for your help in this. I get that I can make a new object like you stated, or I can leave it anonymous. But now the List I have is still not of type Person. This is where I am stuck. I am really looking to return a list of the LINQ entity class Person.

Comment: I certainly don't disagree that it might not be the best thing to do...But, lemme give that a try and see what happens.

Comment: That will work!

It's messy, but it will get the job done. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Well, maybe I spoke too soon. It looks to me like in the second statement at the point where it is creating the new Person object, it is still making a call to the database to and returning all the columns. 

I should have been more clear about my problem being that I have some columns with large amounts of binary that I don't want to retrieve from the database.

Comment: @unknown (google): no you are wrong. The first part (before AsEnumerable) is evaluated on the server, returning instances of the anonymous type. The second part is completely client side. You are taking each instance of the anonymous type and manually transforming it to a Person class by setting the properties, completely in C#. BTW, you can verify this by looking at the SQL generated by the query using things like LINQ to SQL debugger visualizer.

Comment: Hmm. That's what I thought it was doing, but for some reason when I look at SQL Profiler I see the query that is actually run and it is still selecting all columns...

Comment: I dunno. I'm stumped for now and I need to call it a night. Thanks again for the help. I'll update this when I figure it out.

Comment: I think I discovered the source of the why its selecting ALL columns and it has to do with properties I am selecting. One of the properties is actually from a partial class and it gets its value from a related table. For example the property is FriendCount and the table is related to Person. Essentially LINQ is going Persons.Friends.Count

I think it is here that LINQ is selecting all columns for the Person table in order to get access to the Friend table. Or something...

Comment: Probably. Whatever it is, you should look for it in your original LINQ query. Definitely, things done after `AsEnumerable()` cannot run on server so it can't cause any problems.

Comment: just want to mention new Person { a.Name, a.Age } is not gonna compile, you must type new Person { Name = a.Name, Age = a.Age } like in the initial question

Comment: @CyberFox `new {a.Name, a.Age}` is different from `new Person {a.Name, a.Age}` that you wrote (which is nonexistent in the answer)

Comment: @MehrdadAfshari First and second examples

Comment: @CyberFox Huh, I just noticed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was in fact that one of the properties was a relation to another table. I changed my LINQ query so that it could get the same data from a different method without needing to load the entire table.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Make a call to the DB searching with myid (Id of the row) and get back specific columns:

```
var columns = db.Notifications
                .Where(x => x.Id == myid)
                .Select(n => new { n.NotificationTitle, 
                                   n.NotificationDescription, 
                                   n.NotificationOrder });
```