# How to get entity while filtering out certain columns

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, .net-3.5

I have a table with huge columns. How I can select entities without filling properties that are mapped to those columns?

I have one idea, but I'm not sure if it's the right approach:

```
ctx.Items.Where(....).Select(a=> new Item { ... bind only needed columns }).ToList()
```

Will those entities be attached to the DataContext?

Answer (score 2):

Use any type other than `Item`. E.g., an anonymous type or DTO. Then your query will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You are going the right way I think. That's the way for instantiating objects with only the preffered columns / properties filled. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646267/entity-framework-select-specific-columns-and-return-strongly-typed-without-losi).

EDIT:

This is from Julie Lerman and is what is asked in this question I believe:

> Projections with LINQ Query Methods To
>   project using LINQ’s method-based
>   query syntax, you would use the Select
>   method and then identify the
>   properties you want in its parameter.
>   The method-based query syntax requires
>   the syntax for creating an anonymous
>   type in the lambda (see Example 4-4).
>
> Example 4-4. Projecting using LINQ’s
>   method-based syntax
>
> context.Contacts .Where(c =>
>   c.FirstName == "Robert") .Select(c =>
>   new {c.Title, c.LastName,
>   c.FirstName})

Comment: His query will fail at runtime. Try it.

Comment: Why does it fail Craig? And what would be a solution? If Dmitriy ever reads this.

Comment: It will fail because you're not allowed to project onto entity types. Like I said: Try it; the error message is clear enough. I already gave a solution in my answer.