# How to select certain fields from class with IQueryable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an `IQueryable<MainObjectTest>` in which there are several fields, but I only need to pull out certain ones (Title and NestedObject).

How can I do this with dynamic select expression?

```
   public class TestIQueryable
    {

        public IQueryable GetObjectData(IQueryable<MainObjectTest> data)
        {
            IQueryable requredDataFields = data.Select("new(Title, NestedObject)");
            return requredDataFields;
        }
        public class MainObjectTest
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public NestedClassTest NestedObject { get; set; }
        }

        public class NestedClassTest
        {
            public string Field1 { get; set; }
            public string Field2 { get; set; }
            public string Field3 { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Usually you would use the [`Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) extension method from LINQ. The Stack Overflow question "[LINQ to SQL - How to select specific columns and return strongly typed list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094931/linq-to-sql-how-to-select-specific-columns-and-return-strongly-typed-list)" might be useful to reference here. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I  tried to pull out simple properties(Title) and it works fine for me ... Only problem to pull out class object .

Comment: Did you try with using `System.Linq.Dynamic` as `data.Select("new(Title, NestedObject.Field1)")`;

Comment: Selim, how i can do this if there will be array of "NestedObject" ?

Comment: Yes it works too, I have added answer with array object as well. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using model, here steps:

1. Map all data from database into model if you have nested object => use ToList().
2. Use DynamicLinq library to select certain fields from model as IQueryable.

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

What about making an interface:

```
interface Interface1
{
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public NestedClassTest NestedObject { get; set; }
}
```

Implement the interface in you class and let GetObjectData return the interface

```
public IQueryable GetObjectData(IQueryable<Interface1> data)
{
    IQueryable requredDataFields = data.Select();
    return requredDataFields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an anonymous object like this.

```
IQueryable requredDataFields = data.Select(x => new {  x.Title,  x.NestedObject });
```

Comment: I know how to use anonymous object, but i need to use string expression to get only certain fields that coming with FRONTEND request.

Comment: @Librain Sorry for misunderstanding the question. Does this question help with what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select